# Writing to stdout from an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My aim is to extend the eclipse QuickFix component and automate the process of solving syntax errors. Basically, the QuickFix component provides a list of solutions and my task is to select the best possible fix and apply it to the buggy code. But, for now I've been requested to print the resolutions for a marker in the console. I've tried to work out a tutorial and I'm kind of stuck right now. The tutorial I've tried to workout is: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370625&seqNum=21 
I've first added the extension in my plugin.xml file

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution">
    <markerResolutionGenerator
        markerType="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"
        class="org.eclipse.escript.quickfix.QuickFixer"/>
</extension>
```

Then i have created the two classes QuickFixer and QuickFix.

```java
package quickfixer;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IMarkerResolution;
import org.eclipse.ui.IMarkerResolutionGenerator;

class QuickFixer implements IMarkerResolutionGenerator {

    public IMarkerResolution[] getResolutions(IMarker arg0) {
    try {
            Object problem = arg0.getAttribute("Whatsup");
            return new IMarkerResolution[] {
            new QuickFix("Fix #1 for "+problem),
            new QuickFix("Fix #2 for "+problem),
            };
        } catch(CoreException e) {
            return new IMarkerResolution[0];
        }
    }
}
```

then the class QuickFix:

```java
package quickfixer;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.IMarkerResolution;

public class QuickFix implements IMarkerResolution {

       String label;
       QuickFix(String label) {
          this.label = label;
       }
       public String getLabel() {
          return label;
       }

    public void run(IMarker arg0) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(null, "QuickFix Demo",
                     "This quick-fix is not yet implemented");
        System.out.println("Label: " + label);              
    }
}
```

I've managed to correct all the errors i encountered and then i have run the plugin.
I have not been able to get the label printed out in the console.Any suggestions???...

Comment: I'd suggest to rephrase the title of your question. It hasn't anything to do with QuickFix, just using stdout from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Using `System.out` is not a good idea. Check the [relevant FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_does_System.out_and_System.err_output_go?) on why

> you should avoid using standard output or standard error in your
>   plug-in

and use proper logging (or the debugger).

Comment: As i said in the beginning my aim is to automate the quickFix component..But for now i'm trying to 'capture' an error in a buggy program and then when the quickFix pops up, I get to capture the resolutions and print it on the console...Sooo i think it is related to QuickFix as I'm not only printing in the console, I have to get the marker first and afterwards the resolutions for the captured marker.

Comment: @DaroRoyoss Have you verified in the debugger that you actually reach the `println` statement?

Comment: I have tried to but I've not been able. For now, let's omit the printing in the console part. When i run the program and try to use the QuickFix component to fix an error, I don't get the message dialog which should notify user that the quick hasn't been implemented..if i manage get this part right then I'll try to figure out a way to get the resolution printed out in the console...so can you please help me here?

Comment: @DaroRoyoss Then you should clarify in your question that "to get the label printed out in the console" is not the problem, but that apparently the `run()`-method doesn't get called.